# How do I use PDO prepared statements to build an array, and then use array to populate drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using a script that I got from somewhere else that gives me an admin panel in my website.

This template utilises PDO, and I am not familiar with exactly how it works, and would like to learn more but have hit a dead end. I am trying to populate an array with usernames from my database, and then use the array to populate a drop down list on a webpage.

Here is my (attempted) code for the array:

```
function getUserList(){
    $userList = array();
    $sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT username FROM ".TBL_USERS);  
    $options=""; 
    while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
    $userList[$row['username']] = $row['username']; 
        }
        return $userList;
    }
```

and here mis my attempt to call the array into the drop down list:

```
 <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="user">Username:</label></td>

        <td align="left"><select name="user" id="user">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Username to Assign</option>
        <?php echo $database->getUserList(); ?>
        </select></td>
 </tr>
```

Now there is a VERY good chance that what I have done is COMPLETELY incorrect but go easy on me LOL!

Comment: Start by inspecting what you've got: `var_dump($database->getUserList());` if it worked as it looks like, you'll have an array whose keys and values are _both_ the usernames.  Then it's just a matter of writing a `foreach` loop to display `<option>` tags for each element in the array `getUserList()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael. Having both the Key and Value the same won't be an issue will it?

Comment: No, no issue at all, just maybe unnecessary.

Comment: ok when you say unnecessary, what is the alternative? I simply copied that code and tried to adapt it to my needs, so any additional info that will help me learn the way it works would help ALOT

Comment: I mean it's redundant, since you are getting 2 copies of the username per array element. You could instead just do `$userlist[] = $row['username'];` If you were returning another value like a numeric user_id, it might help to index the array with it `$userlist[$row['user_id']] = $row['username'];`

Comment: Oh yeh i get that now. Awesome man, thanks for that. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getUserList()` method returns an array, not a string you can `echo`.

If you want to echo an option list of all elements in that array, you can either loop through the result in your view:

```
foreach ($database->getUserList() as $key => $value)
{
  echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

Or you do it in the method (probably another method that takes the array and returns the list).

Comment: thanks Jeroen. like I said, I am new to this… that foreach loop would go into the drop down list <select></select> tags?? or as part of the function?

Comment: @Djinné22 This you can put directly in the html. Personally I would have another method that returns the list (converts it from an array to a string), but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I will go learn how to put that into a separate method. I appreciate the leg up :-)